# ASP.NET MVC Routing : Dynamic Names for Action Methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing

Currently I have a Controller named StoreController. There are three Categories : books, movies, and games. How can i make sure that the url's

- *http://mywebsite.com/store/books*,
- *http://mywebsite.com/store/movies*
- *http://mywebsite.com/store/games*

match a single action method. Right now, I am having three separate action methods `books(); movies(); games();` doing the same thing, i.e listing the products in them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try like this?

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Store", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
                , null }
                )
```

and you make Controller like

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    if(id == "books"){


    }
    else if(id == "movies"){

    }
    else{// this is null case


    }

    return Content("hello");// test
}
```